# How to read this kind of text file in java

Tags: java, printing, text-files

How to read this kind of text file in java ,please help ...
This text file use as a template to my java program I am trying to read this file it showing whatever there in text file but I want to place those {0} ... which java content .

```
Q799,B080+000
q831
rN
S4
D7
ZT
JF
OD,P
R24,0
N

X555,56,2,780,714
A771,73,1,1,2,1,N,"A  {0}"
A742,70,1,1,2,2,N,"   {1}({31})"
A765,450,1,1,2,2,N,"SCREEN-{38}"
A706,86,1,2,1,1,N,"Adm   :Rs.{6}"
A682,86,1,2,1,1,N,"E.TAX :Rs.{28}"
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing some code for OP.

Comment: if you want to store it as a key value pair then use Map instead of java array

Comment: Ok Can you please help me with that actually I want to print that on TSC printer how can I do that ?

Comment: google it . it is easily available .

Comment: @Rinku i think you have to mention all the problem in your post but first you have to try something we are here only to correct your code or for suggestion not to do your complete work

Answer (score 2):

Here's try following code:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\CountryJSONFile.json")); 
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject .keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ){
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    String value = jsonObject.getString(key); 
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Maps` to store key value pair rather than arrays:-

```
HashMap<String,String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
jsonMap.put("Name",(String) jsonObject.get("Name"));
jsonMap.put("ShowTime",(String) jsonObject.get("ShowTime"));
jsonMap.put("Total",(String) jsonObject.get("Total"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String readFile(String folder, String file) {
    logger.info("Read file ...");
    Stream<String> lines = null;
    try {
      lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(folder, file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String txt = lines.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    lines.close();
    logger.info("File is ready");
    return txt;
  }


private User jsonToProductTypes(String json){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return  gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
  }


User is a class with the same structure as the json 
User can contain other objects , after you have a java object you can do what ever you want
```

Comment: I think it's important to point out that `Gson` is an external library by Google. `JSONObject` is a separate library entirely, so this solution wouldn't be what OP is really looking for.

Comment: and i am also using java 8